# CakePHP: 404 when requesting resources from server

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm having this problem in my production server. I need to install my local copy of cakephp into a subdiorectory domain.com/cakephp, the I can see al it's contents correctly, the problem comes when the code requests for a controller/method using ajax. I believe this may have something to do with the .htacess, since I got this from javascript console in Chrome:

`POST http://domain.com/clientes/lista_grid 404 (Not Found)`
when it should be something like
`POST http://domain.com/cakephp/clientes/lista_grid 404 (Not Found)`.

I've tried every possible .htaccess configuration for a cakephp subdirectory install. But no luck, I've got no idea what to do with this.

Comment: post header information

Comment: You mean it doesn't work because you're posting to the wrong url? There's an easy fix for that =). If that's not what your problem is, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @AD7six Thanks solved!, It was .htacess problem and me using relative urls to access controllers methods not cakephp methods

Comment: Please post as an answer (with more detail), or delete the question if you think it will not help any future visitors